.net maui deferred deep linking
We're writing a cross-platform app in .net maui.
We want the user to be able to send a (deep) link via text that will result in the recipient's device opening the app if it's installed or redirect to the app in the App Store or Play Store.
From what We can see the only approach is to have a web service and create a link to that service which results in the service calling back to the device to start the app and if the device responds indicating that that fails then it sends an app store download link.
Is this the only/best way of doing that?

Do you mean Android app links and Apple universal links?

Yeah it seems that App Links and Universal Links are the current way of doing it. However, it seems a bit onerous in that you need to have a website registered and configured appropriately, and (at least for App Links) the app itself needs to be in the store first (which makes testing difficult). Supposedly the older way of just configuring an app to intercept custom links and start up on the device if its installed should still work, but our basic testing, with simulators in VS 2022, couldn't make that work.

Yes you are right. For Apple Universal Links, it needs to  register the App ID and add the associated domains. Though it's the recommended way.

I am a bit confused by what you mean by From what We can see the only approach is to have a web service and create a link to that service which results in the service calling back to the device to start the app. But essentially, the text message will contain a url which is registered in the app for android and ios (can contain query params, to be handled in app). And then when the user clicks the url, the OS will determine if there exists a registered app for app link and open the correct app or store to download.

So, if a link like "https://com.myapp/page?param1=value1" is activated/clicked on a device then if the app is not currently installed the device will automatically launch the app store or play store to the correct page for installing that app?
